# I need to change links without changing page

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

I have a site that use Jquery, so when I click on the menu "contact" it open a contact page but the link still the same, I wanna change to "index.html#contact" when I click in contact on the menu AND if someone copy the link index.html#contact it automatically open the contact page.
Thats all :) thanks in advance !

Html :

```
<div class="mainbox">
    <div class="main">
        <a><div class="menu" id="menu1">
            <div class="menuimg" id="menuimg1"></div>
            <div class="menutxt" id="menutxt1">Menu1</div>
        </div></a>

        <a><div class="menu" id="menu2">
            <div class="menuimg" id="menuimg2"></div>
            <div class="menutxt" id="menutxt2">Menu2</div>
        </div></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery :

```
$('#menu1').click(function(){
    if($('.container2').is(':visible')){
        $('.container2').hide();
        $('.container1').show();
    });
$('#menu2').click(function(){
    if($('.container1').is(':visible')){
        $('.container1').hide();
        $('.container2').show();
    });
```

Comment: please show us the code for your menu.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple idea of how to go about it if you'd like to try it out. My example provides retrieving the url hash (if there is one) on document ready with window.location.hash, and loading the tab. I've also provided a simple tab structure that you may be able to work from, as well as a click event handler.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            //Check for hash in the url
            $(document).ready(function(){
                //Retrieve the hash using
                //window.location.hash
                var hash = window.location.hash;
                //Check if the hash is set.
                if( hash )
                    //Ifso, load the tab.
                    loadTab(hash);
            });

            //Click event handler for menu
            $(document).on("click", ".tab", function(e){
                //Prevent the default action
                e.preventDefault();
                //Set the target to this elements href
                var target = $(this).attr("href");
                //Load the tab
                loadTab(target);
            });

            //Load the tab
            function loadTab(target)
            {
                //Check if the target does exist:
                if($(target).length > 0) {
                    //Hide the other tab pages
                    $(".tab-page").hide();
                    //Show this one.
                    $(target).show();
                }
            }
        </script>
        <style>
            .tab-page{ display:none; }
            .default{ display:block; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a class="tab" href="#home">Home</a> | <a class="tab" href="#contact">Contact Us</a>
        <div>
            <div class="tab-page default" id="home">
                Hello, this is the <b>Home</b> page.
            </div>
            <div class="tab-page" id="contact">
                Hello, this is the <b>Contact</b> page!
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope that helps!